# Using Wait Until Event in Marketing Cloud to generate task from click in email

Tags: journeybuilder, marketingcloudapi

Using Wait Until Event to generate task from click in email

Hello, I have a use case that needs to generate a Sales Cloud task immediately following a click on a CTA in an email, the task will generate later in the journey and that part works. With the help of other online sources, I have the CloudPage code, but I am unable to get it to work for the Wait Until Event. It keeps generating very generic errors that I can't seem to find answers to. Any help is greatly appreciated, I am a beginner SFMC developer. Here's my code:

%%[
SET @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
]%%

Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
try {
  
    var SubscriberKey = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@SubscriberKey")
    
    var authEndpoint = 'https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/'  
    var payload = {
        client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",            
        client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",     
        grant_type: "client_credentials"
                  };
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token'
    var contentType = 'application/json'
 
    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token
        var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url;
  
     {
        var headerNames = "Authorization";
        var headerValues = "Bearer " + accessToken;
        var jsonBody = {
            "ContactKey": SubscriberKey,                      
            "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx", 
             "Data": { Subscriber_Key : SubscriberKey, 
                      EventDate : new Date()
              
            }    
        };
 
        var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + "interaction/v1/events";
 
        var fireEntryEvent = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, Platform.Function.Stringify(jsonBody), headerNames, headerValues);
        var respo = fireEntryEvent.Response.toString();
       
    };
 
} catch (error) {
    Platform.Response.Write("

### Sorry, something went wrong.

" + Platform.Function.Stringify(error));
}

Comment: Formatting your question makes it more readable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting